# how to load multiple PDF file in ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf, uiwebview

I have 4 PDF files stored locally in Xcode.  I want to place all the PDFs into an array and then display them in a `UITableView`. When the user selects any one of them, it should open in next `ViewController`. Here is the sample code for displaying one PDF file but I need multiple PDF files to be listed:

```
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webpage loadRequest:request];
```

Please provide some sample code.

Comment: Do you want to show all of the PDFs at once, or do you just want to show the names and allow the user to select which one they want to open?

Comment: just want to show the names and allow the user to select which one they want to open

Comment: Are these four files static, or is this a dynamic list that will change?

Comment: static only i just want to add this pdf into array and display its in tableview when user select the pdf file should be open in uiviewcontroller this the work flow

Answer (score 0):

The way you are going about loading the PDF into the `webpage` object is a good start. To make this code more dynamic to work with an array of objects, you will need to start by implementing the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDatasource` protocols in your view controller. Next, you will need to create an `NSArray` of your URLs as an instance property on the view controller class. In the .m file add this above your `@implementation` section:

```
@interface MyViewController ()
<
    UITableViewDataSource,
    UITableViewDelegate
>

@property NSArray *pdfFileUrls;

@end
```

Then make sure you implement all of the required methods for the two `UITableView` protocols.  The compiler will give you warnings for any required methods that are not implemented, so just pay attention to those.

Then in either your initializer or viewDidLoad, populate the array:

```
self.pdfFileUrls = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"url1", @"url2", @"url2", @"url4", nil];
```

Assuming your file URLs contain the file name (as in your example), you can then use the URL inside this array to create your labels for the table view cell.  Inside of the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, use this code to assign the label:

```
static NSString* identifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

NSString* theFileName = [[[self.pdfFileUrls objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension]
cell.textLabel.text = theFileName;
```

Finally, in the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, you will need to get the correct URL from the array:

```
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.pdfFileUrls objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webpage loadRequest:request];
```

Let me know if you have any questions about this.

Comment: your answer is partially correct , can you modify your answer for get the name from pdf in local path

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?  The string that gathers the file name from the URL should be doing that for you. Are you saying that you don't know URLs in advance but you are grabbing them on the fly?

Comment: Can you give me more information about what exactly is happening?  Is it crashing?  Or is it just not displaying anything?

Comment: this is not an actual method dude

Comment: I didn't give you methods. I gave you code to put inside of the `viewDidLoad`, `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Best way for previewing Documents ..

`QLPreviewController` and `UIDocumentInteractionController`, provides a specialised view for previewing Documents like PDF, Excel, PPTX, Word etc.By using these API You can present it modally in full screen or You can navigate to next Page.

Have a look into below Link...

http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/preview-documents-with-qlpreviewcontroller.html